# How to show a wait message OR loading image when a write operation is being performed using spapi_lists.js library.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am using SPAPI_Lists.js and SPAPI_Core.js libraries to update/add records to share point 2007 lists.

i want to show a wait message OR loading image still the write or read operation is completed.

Please suggest me how this can be done.

here is the code

```
    var list = new SPAPI_Lists("ListURL");

         var newItem =  {               
                    Title: "News",
                    Link: "LinkURL"
                };

   var items = list.quickAddListItem("List ID", newItem);
```

As the above code indicates, i want to show a wait message OR loading icon still the `quickAddListItem` is completed

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mmhhhh ... Do you have any documentation about these libraries ? If `quickAddListItem` is not asynchronous, then you cannot do what you're trying to achieve.
Or you can try showing your loading image first, and then call `setTimeout`:

```
$('.my_loading_img').show();
// 500 means to wait 500ms before doing the adding... you can try a smaller number
setTimeout(function() {
    var list = new SPAPI_Lists("ListURL");
    var newItem =  {               
              Title: "News",
              Link: "LinkURL"
          };
    var items = list.quickAddListItem("List ID", newItem);
}, 500);
```

Otherwise, I created a JS library that deals with Sharepoint webservices : http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/

With my library and your example:

```
// show your loading image
$('.my_loading_img').show(); // jquery
// call SharepointPlus
$SP().list("ListName").add({Title:"News",Link:"LinkURL"},
  {
    error:function(items) {
      alert("Error when adding the item");
      $('.my_loading_img').hide(); // hide the image
    },
    success:function(items) {
      alert("Item added!");
      $('.my_loading_img').hide(); // hide the image
    }
  }
);
```